# Run procedure in SSIS with temp table

Tags: ssis

I have procedure that contains two parts:
1- I have a select to insert data into temporary table
[image]

2- I have this to export to csv.
[image]
On SSIS when I try ti run this procedure I got this error
[image]

Is any way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you insert the data in the table temp?

Comment: Please see the first screenshot.

Comment: I saw it. But I didn't understand why you don't perform the same selection with all conversions directly?

Comment: I did not understand your question?

Comment: You can make the second selection from the destination table with the `OLE DB Source` component. Insert the data into the file using `Flat File Destination` component.

Answer (score 0):

ssis creates a new connection per component. For this reason, in the execution of the second code, it does not have access to the temp table.

To solve this problem, there are two solutions:

- Use two sharp `##Export_Table` in creating the temp table (global temporary table).
- In ssis, change the `retainSameConnection` option to `true` in the `connection properties` window

Comment: Sorry but your solutions did not solve my problem

Comment: So, the problem is with the temp table. You must change your ways

Comment: Please tell me which option worked

Comment: any of them works. 
1- I found this error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure dbo.usp_export_HSBC_installments, Line 122 [Batch Start Line 0]
Invalid object name '##Export_table'.
2- I changed the connection properties and I have found the same error

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a temp table is created by stored procedure then it will be local to that stored procedure and it will be dropped automatically once execution of stored procedure is completed. You need to create the temporary table in execute sql task then execute stored procedure and then data flow.

Create Temp Table (Execute SQL Task) --> Execute Stored Procedure (Execute SQL Task) --> Data Flow Task